# Botão para adicionar novos campos em um form, com JS puro

Tags: javascript, html

Quero criar um formulário com um botão `+`, que crie mais campos para que o usuário possa enviar quantos formulários quiser.

Tentei este código, mas sem sucesso:

```
   var coluna = 1;
    function plus() {
        document.write('<button onclick="plus()">+</button><br><hr><br>');
        document.write("<form action='teste.php' name='form'>");
        coluna = coluna + 1;
        botao = coluna - 1;
        espacos = '<br><input type="text" name="assunto'+coluna+'"><br><br><textarea name="texto'+coluna+'" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea><br><br><button onclick="plus()">+</button><br><hr><br>';
        document.write("teste");
        document.write(coluna);
        document.write(espacos);
        document.write('<button onclick="document.form.submit()" id="submit'+coluna+'" name="rows" value="'+coluna+'">Enviar</button><br>');
        //document.write('<input type="submit" id="submit'+coluna+'" name="submit'+coluna+'" value="enviar">');
        document.getElementById('submit'+botao+'').style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.write("</form>");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo bem simples de como adicionar `div`s com campos em um form já existente:

```js
var line = 1;
function addInput(divName) {
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.innerHTML  = '['+line +']';
  newdiv.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="text'+line +'_1" id="text'+line +'_1">';
  newdiv.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="text'+line +'_2" id="text'+line +'_2">';
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  line++;
}

addInput('lines');
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div id="lines"></div>
  <button type="button" onclick="addInput('lines')">+</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Se preferir, teste no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/ozmEdo)**.

Note que não estamos usando `document.write`, mas sim criando os elementos diretamente com `createElement`.

Se quiser realmente `form`s separados, basta trocar o `('div')` por `('form')`, e remover o `form` do `html`. Mas lembre-se que neste caso você pode ter problemas com o envio dos dados, caso o usuário altere mais de um campo.

O `button` precisa do `type="button"` para evitar que ele envie o `form` (o *type* padrão é `submit`).